# ERROR 2017 : Internal error creating job configuration

Tags: apache-pig

The following code on execution pops up an error saying **ERROR 2017 : Internal error creating job configuration.** in PIG.

```
data = LOAD 'info.txt' USING PigStorage();

name_col_one = FOREACH data GENERATE $0 AS timeStamp, $1 AS one, $2 AS two, $3 AS info, $4 AS four, $5 AS five, $6 AS six, $7 AS seven, $8 AS eight, $9 AS nine, $10 AS ten, $11  AS eleven;

process_col_one = FOREACH name_col_one GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(timeStamp,'\\s+',2)) AS (time:chararray, date:chararray), one, two;

new_timestamp = FOREACH process_col_one GENERATE CONCAT(date,CONCAT(' ',time)), one, two;

sys_info = FOREACH name_col_one GENERATE info;

split_  = FOREACH sys_info GENERATE REPLACE(info, '\\[', '') AS new_split;
split_again  = FOREACH split_ GENERATE REPLACE(new_split, ']', '\t') AS final_split;

others = FOREACH name_col_one GENERATE four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven;

r1 = RANK new_timestamp;
r2 = RANK split_again;
r3 = RANK others;

final = JOIN r1 BY rank_new_timestamp, r2 BY rank_split_again;
DUMP final;
```

**SAMPLE DATA in info.txt**

23:58:19 02/23/2015 good    1042559519  [Linux][Baseline][lrtp2nosqlprod1][FileSystem][/tmp]    FileSystems/tmp\Use%=1%    9:5603  0   1

23:58:15 02/23/2015 good    1042559519  [Linux][Baseline][lrtp2nosqlprod1][FileSystem][/boot]   FileSystems/boot\Use%=37%  3:5603  0   37

23:58:15 02/23/2015 good    1042559537  [Linux][Baseline][lrtp2nosqlprod1][Process][srmclient][SiSExclude]  running 3:5599  running true    no data 1   0   0

23:58:15 02/23/2015 good    1042559537  [Linux][Baseline][lrtp2nosqlprod1][Process][OSWatcher][SiSExclude]  running, 2 processes    4:5599  running true    no data 2   0   0

**Relations**
new_timestamp is reversing the timestamp from the input dat,
split_again is removing square brackets in $3 and delimiting them by '\t'.

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias final
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:880)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:774)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.PigException: ERROR 1002: Unable to store alias final
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:982)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.store(PigServer.java:942)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:855)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobCreationException: ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:873)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.compile(JobControlCompiler.java:298)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:190)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1322)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1307)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.storeEx(PigServer.java:978)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.JobControlCompiler.getJob(JobControlCompiler.java:817)
    ... 19 more
================================================================================
```

Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your post to add a sample of your input data and the complete stack trace please. Which version of Pig are you using?

Comment: I can DUMP r1, r2 and r3.
I get the error only when I dump final.

Comment: ok but can you please add it? And which version of Pig are you using? We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: It works for me using 0.14.0. Back in Pig 0.12.0, when Pig couldn't find a file, instead of showing a decent error message it displayed just what you posted... Are you sure you are using the correct path in the HDFS? If you type in your console `hadoop fs -cat info.txt` you see the contents of the file?

Comment: Yes, I can see the file

Comment: Must be a bug that was fixed in 0.13 or 0.14 then. We will need to check the stack trace to see where is the error coming from. Can you please add it?

Comment: [This bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3985) seems to be the problem. Try running the script with multiquery disabled: `pig -no_multiquery -f your_script.pig`

Comment: The mapReduceLauncher is stuck at 97% since then :P

Comment: did it end? Did it work?

Comment: final = JOIN r1 BY rank_new_timestamp, r2 BY rank_split_again; is it rank_new_timestamp or new_timestamp,rank_split_again or split_again

Comment: It is still running @Balduz
It is rank_new_timestamp

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been reported before (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3469) and has been fixed, maybe try using the latest version of pig.

This problem can sometimes be fixed by specifying the path to the input data file
e.g.  '/home/user/doc/info.txt'